# Как вывести из одного поля несколько значений в mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица mysql, в ней есть в поле screens. В этом поле может быть несколько ссылок на фото, каждая фотка разделяется запятой:

```
https://site.ru/foto1.jpg, https://site.ru/foto2.jpg, https://site.ru/foto3.jpg
```

Как мне на php вывести скажем только 2-ю фотографию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще изначально хочу сказать, что такое хранение фоток супернеоптимальное по различным причинам. Особенно с жёсткой привязкой к хосту (хранение `https://site.ru/`
при смене названия сайта вам аукнется)

А в целом можно сделать через **[explode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)**

```
$images = explode(',', ТУТ_СТРОКА_ИЗ_БД);
echo $images[1]; // Вторая фотка хранится под индексом 1
```

Comment: Спасибо, а почему не оптимальное хранение? Что посоветуете? Я думал сделать 10 отдельных полей для фото, но так тоже будет не очень?

Comment: Обычно делают колонку image где хранят относительный путь.... а в другой таблице image_id